# convert a pdf embedding html to pdf

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

Alright, this might sound a little bit crazy, but there it is.

Lately i built a web page that could contain other documents. now, some of them could have been files from the web, hence I used an Iframe to show them too.

here's a visual explanation: [image]

now, it works and everyone is happy. then, i was told that one should be able to print this as a pdf.

this also works, the pdf converter somehow recognized the content of the iframe and was able to convert it too (note: those files are not cross domain)

but now, I am requested to allow having those files also pdf, not only html, and that does not work at all.

in a straight question: how can I convert to pdf, the content of an iframe, which is also a pdf file?

did anyone encounter such a crazy thing, is that even possible to be done?

Comment: please provide jsfiddle for the same

Comment: do you have iframes with html inside or with pdf inside? In case of iframes with html you may want to show Print dialog (in Chrome, in Safari) which is capable to print into PDF. If you have PDFs inside iframes then you may just merge these PDFs into the single one using the server side code